# Using in_array looks correct but is throwing errors

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have problem using in_array search, but code looks fine. What on earth am I missing.

```
$postCats = wp_get_post_categories($postId, array('orderby' => 'term_order', 'order' => 'ASC')); 

$prevCategoryName = array();

foreach($postCats as $cat) {
    $categoryName = get_cat_name($cat);
    if (!in_array($categoryName, $prevCategoryName)) {
        $most_latest_post .= '<div class="postCatTags">' . $categoryName . '</div>';
    }
    $prevCategoryName = array_push($prevCategoryName, $categoryName);
}
```

Displayed error messages:

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testwp2\wp-content\themes\my-theme\template-frontpage.php
>   on line 119
>
> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testwp2\wp-content\themes\my-theme\template-frontpage.php
>   on line 122

Comment: It's telling you that `$prevCategoryName` is not an array, but rather than integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this line

```
$prevCategoryName = array_push($prevCategoryName, $categoryName);
```

to

```
array_push($prevCategoryName, $categoryName);
```

Comment: Happens to us all.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is corrected code:**

```
$postCats = wp_get_post_categories($postId, array('orderby' => 'term_order', 'order' => 'ASC')); 

$prevCategoryName = array();
$most_latest_post = "";
foreach($postCats as $cat) {
    $categoryName = get_cat_name($cat);
    if (!in_array($categoryName, $prevCategoryName)) {
        $most_latest_post .= '<div class="postCatTags">' . $categoryName . '</div>';
    }
    array_push($prevCategoryName, $categoryName);
}
```